# Как сделать что-бы при нажатии на пункт в ListView из него копировалось числовое значение?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать что-бы при нажатии на пункт в ListView из него копировалось числовое  значение  между первым и вторим знаком $ и заносилось в переменную.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        private ListView lv;


        private String s = "text from item";




        public Elements content;
        public ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);


            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.view);
            new NewThread().execute();

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_dark, R.id.pro_item, titleList);

        }

        public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
                Document doc;
                try {

                    doc = Jsoup.connect("https://coinmarketdaddy.com/currencies/all").maxBodySize(0).get();
                    content = doc.select("tr");

                    titleList.clear();

                    for (Element contents : content) {
                        titleList.add(contents.text());

                    }



                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);


            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);


                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                        Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, ("ok"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        s = s.substring(s.indexOf("$") + 1);
                        s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("$"));
                    }
                });


            }}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                // берём строку из списка по нажатой позиции
                String row = titleList.get(i);
                // находим первый $
                int start = row.indexOf("$");
                if (start == -1) { // если не нашли
                    Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Not have data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }   
                // находим второй $
                int end = row.indexOf("$", start + 1);
                if (end == -1) { // если не нашли
                    Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Not have data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                // вырезаем кусок из строки по найденным позициям
                // и присваиваем переменной
                s = row.substring(start + 1, end);
            }
        });
```